# SSIS Exec T-Sql Statement Task connection string

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I dragged Execute t-sql statement task from toolbox. clicked new and created new connection.
when i executed, it executed successfully. there was no db showing in con string.

i changed the connection string to point to new server of above in Connection tab.
when i executed it, i recv errr

**Description: Executing the query "DBCC SHRINKFILE (AppDB_log,300);" failed with the following error: "Could not locate file 'AppDB_log' for database 'master' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped. ". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error**

**DBCC Shrinkdatabase command i am using.**

Comment: We need more information than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the query directly in SSMS in the database where you *think* it will be run based on your connection. If it fails then it's probably a problem with the query (i.e. the data file really doesn't exist). If it succeeds then it's probably a problem with your connection.

If it's a problem with the connection, try running profiler on your server and see what pops up when you run the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

Copuld it be a permissions problem? Do you have the rights to run the command on that database?